# Is there an intuitive, physical way to see the line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

The way I am thinking of a line integral intuitively is if I had a copper wire, that was poorly made and had different densities throughout the wire, then I could chop the wire up into several pieces, and use the density at that piece and the length of the copper wire to find the mass of the wire at that point. This is what the line integral is calculating to me. Am I right in thinking this? Is there a better way to visualize the line integral? I am already familiar with the work and physics examples so I was trying to come up with a way to visualize the integral in another way.

Comment: I think you'll like this video. The same channel has a couple other videos on this topic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WA5_a3C2iqY

Comment: Have you already seen [the image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#/media/File:Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif) on [the Wikipedia page for line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field) showing how to interpret the line integral of a scalar field as a signed area? If so, can you elaborate on what you are not satisfied by?
**Edit:** Since you mention "work" in physics, maybe you're also interested in the line integral of a *vector* field, which is lower on that page and has a similar award-winning gif for illustration.